# Dbeaver TIMESTAMPDIFF function doesn't work

Tags: dbeaver, timestampdiff

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18gW7.png)

Is there any equivalent function in dbeaver? the function doesn't appear when y try to list. I atach image in my dbeaver. It's my Mac? Anyone pass this problem?
Thanks

In MYSQL Workbench appears and works fine

Comment: Even though the function might not appear in the DBeaver UI list, try to use it anyway to see if it works? ... what versions of MySQL and DBeaver do you have?

Comment: Dbeaver is just a databse client. It may not know all the functions of the underlying databases. Just use tineatampdiff in your query as the query is executed by myaql, not by dbeaver.